# How to find who fill Facebook Leads ads form

Tags: facebook, ads, social-media

Recently, I build facebook ads for getting leads. So I got one but the data which is filled incorrectly. So How I find out who fills the leads form in Facebook ads so I contact him.

Comment: I don’t think you can get any additional info besides what the submitted form contained in the first place.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research about that no one gives me a clear answer. Then I apply my self to check. We got only info that provided into form. with that information, we tried to find out who fill the form such as Person full name search on facebook or search his number in facebook messenger to find out.